# jQuery Validator don`t work correctly

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a simple form to validate where the user has to enter a project name. If current action is "Create" I have to check if the entered value is already in the database and return error message. If it`s edit I have to check if the entered value is different than the current value and in this situation to check again if the new is already in the database.
The code is here:

```
if (((ACTION_CURRENT == ACTION_EDIT) && ($(id).val() != projectData.project.name)) || (ACTION_CURRENT ==  ACTION_CREATE)) {
            initProjectNameValidator();
        } 
        if ($(id).valid()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

 function initProjectNameValidator() {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod('checkDuplicateName', function(value) {
        var isInArray = $.inArray(value, projectsNames);
        return (isInArray == -1);
    }, messages.duplicateProject);

    $('#editProjectDialogForm').validate({
        rules : {
            projectForm_name : {
                required : true,
                checkDuplicateName : true
            }
        }
    });
}
```

At first look, it works fine. But there's a problem when the action is "edit". If I have projects (aaa, bbb, ccc) and I go to project "aaa" and try to change it to "bbb" it properly returns the error message. If I go to project "aaa" and try to change it to "aaa" it properly doesn't return an error message. But here comes the problem. If I go to project "aaa" try to change it to "aaa" there's no problem, but if without refresh try after that to change it to "bbb" there's also no error message, but here have to be an error message. The same happen if I try to change from "aaa" to "bbb" - give error and if without refresh try to change to "aaa" there's an error again but there shouldn't be

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear and it seems like much of the relevant code is missing.  However, there is one obvious error...

Your logic is flawed.  You are trying to use the `.valid()` method before calling the `.validate()` method.

`.validate()` is only used to *initialize* the plugin on your form and must be called first.  Then after it's initialized, you can programmatically trigger validation by calling the `.valid()` method.